# Add a word to a custom taxonomy's term slug in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-taxonomy, slug, taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy called "places" and a term slug in that taxonomy can be something like:

```
"domain.com/places/hong-kong/"
"domain.com/places/usa/"
```

How can i add a word to that third part of the slug, but still have it show the place name?

For example if want to add the word "place", it would be something like that:

```
"domain.com/places/hong-kong-place/"
"domain.com/places/usa-place/"
"domain.com/places/israel-place/"
"domain.com/places/denemark-place/"
```

or

```
"domain.com/places/place-hong-kong/"
"domain.com/places/place-usa/"
"domain.com/places/place-israel/"
"domain.com/places/place-denemark/"
```

*Just to be clear: the part i want to modify is the term title part and not the taxonomy title part.*

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin for custom permalinks. 
 https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/

Or you can use this code to create custom permalinks

```
function reset_permalinks() {
global $wp_rewrite;
$wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure( '/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'reset_permalinks' );
```

Comment: I know of the general ability to make a custom slug, but i don't know how to get the result i explained in my question. so for example with your code example, how would you add a word next to the term title?

Comment: I don't think you can customise the term title part with this method, only the taxonomy title part. so it is a wrong answer.